# Perforce API: Get Latest Revision of a Subdirectory

Tags: python, perforce

I have downloaded and installed the Perforce API for Python.

I'm able to run the examples on this page:
http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4script/03_python.html#1127434

But unfortunately the documentation seems incomplete. For example, the `P4` class has a method called `run_sync`, but it's not documented anywhere (in fact, it doesn't even show up if you run `dir(p4)` in the Python interactive interpreter, despite the fact that you can use the method just fine in the interactive interpreter.)

So I'm struggling with figuring out how to use the API for anything beyond the trivial examples on the page I linked to above.

I would like to write a script which simply downloads the latest revision of a subdirectory to the filesystem of the computer running it and does nothing else. I don't want the server to change in any way. I don't want there to be any indication that the files came from Perforce (as opposed to if you get the files  via the Perforce application, it'll mark the files in your file system as read only until you check them out or whatever. That's silly - I just need to pull down a snapshot of what the subdirectory looked like at the moment the script was run.)

Comment: Is the fact that the files are read-only the only deal breaker for you using the sync functionality?

Comment: Have you tried the example that  creates a client workspace from a template and syncs it?

Comment: @martineau: I have, but I don't want to create new templates, as those would show up on the server, would they not?

Comment: Seems like you could either use the default client spec template, or create your own dummy one from it to use for this purpose.

Comment: If you want the files to be writable, rather than read-only, after you sync them, that is a property of your workspace definition: set the "allwrite" option: http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_client.html

Answer (score 1):

The Python API follows the same basic structure as the command line client (both are very thin wrappers over the same underlying API), so you'll want to look at the command line client documentation; for example, look at "p4 sync" to understand how "run_sync" in P4Python works:

http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r14.2/manuals/cmdref/p4_sync.html

For the task you're describing I would do the following (I'll describe it in terms of Perforce commands since my Python is a little rusty; once you know what commands you're running it should be pretty simple to translate into Python, since the P4Python doc has examples of things like creating and modifying a client spec, which is the hardest part):

1) Create a client that maps the desired depot directory to the desired local filesystem location, e.g. if you want the directory "//depot/foo/..." downloaded to "/usr/team/foo" you'd make a client that looks like:

```
Client: mytempclient123847
Root: /usr/team/foo
View:
    //depot/foo/... //mytempclient123847/...
```

You should set the "allwrite" option on the client since you said don't want the synced files to be read-only:

```
Options: allwrite noclobber nocompress unlocked nomodtime rmdir
```

2) Sync, using the "-p" option to minimize server impact (the server will not record that you "have" the files).

3) Delete the client.

(I'm omitting some details like making sure that you're authenticated correctly -- that's a whole other potential challenge depending on your server's security and whether it's using external authentication, but it sounds like that's not the part you're having trouble with.)

Comment: I didn't know about the -p option, nice.